# Mac app for show all character features in notepad++

Tags: text-editor, internationalization

I am working in 2 environments (Mac & Windows). Once I have problem with invisible characters in Windows and notepad++'s "show all characters" feature helped me a lot in displaying the invisible character (which turns out to be `LF`).

Is there any text editor or any application in Mac that has similar feature? I specifically liked this "show all characters" with whitespace, tab, and CR-LF characters. Other common text editor features I can find in either Atom, Sublime Text, or VS Code and I am pretty happy with them.

Answer (score 1):

BBEdit is a really great Mac text editor, and can show invisible characters.
http://www.barebones.com

Comment: does it include whitespace, tabs, CR, LF?

Comment: It's free to download and try. You don't even have to pay to keep using it in "free" mode. Try it and see if it has what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried it and it is able to show `LF` or `CR` character. But notepad++ is clearer in color-coding.

Comment: Try Atom (atom.io) this also has loads of themes available.